# Multiple Buttons Not Working In Android Application

Tags: android, button, view

I am trying to program an app that has multiple activities all created by one main menu screen. For some reason my code has some errors. I cannot seem to figure out why my onClickListeners and newOnClickListeners are not working as I have seen this same style of multiple button code used on the internet. I have tried using eclipses "fix it" solution but that just makes the app have more errors.

Can anyone see what is going wrong? I would appreciate it a lot, I am new to programming.

Here is my code for the main menus java file

```
package com.fox.hipnyc;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
Button button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
Button button5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
Button button6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);


button1.setOnClickListener(new onclickListener() {  

    public void onclick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

        startActivity(intent1);  

    }

});
button2.setOnClickListener(new onclickListener() {  

    public void onclick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);

        startActivity(intent2);  

    }

});


button3.setOnClickListener(new onclickListener() {  

    public void onclick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Fourth.class);

        startActivity(intent3);  

    }

});

button4.setOnClickListener(new onclickListener() {  

    public void onclick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent4 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Fifth.class);

        startActivity(intent4);  

    }

});
button5.setOnClickListener(new onclickListener() {  

    public void onclick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent5 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Sixth.class);

        startActivity(intent5);  

    }

});


button6.setOnClickListener(new onclickListener() {  

    public void onclick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent6 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Seventh.class);

        startActivity(intent6);  

    }

});
    }
}
```

Comment: print your logcat errors as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code for all 6 buttons of your onlclickListeners:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.clas);

        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

and You dont need to have different Intent variables (intent1,2,3...) for different buttons. One Intent variable 'i' will work for all buttons.

Answer (score 1):

`Java` is case sensitive by the way. Since you are declaring an anonymous class that implements the `OnClickListener` listener, when you initiate it, make sure to capitalize the **"o"** and the **"c"**, that is `new OnClickListener()`.